# Mean Square Prediction Error (MSPE) on out of sample data in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, prediction, lm

I want to calculate the **out of sample** MSPE for a multiple linear regression using R. From my textbook I got the following formula for MSPE

[image]

where [image] meaning that observation *i* have been omitted from the mean.

I tried calculating the MSEP by using the following two lines in R

```
fit <- lm(CO ~ weight + nico, data = df)
mean( (df$CO - predict.lm(fit, df))^2 )
```

However I'm fairly sure that this is in-sampel MSPE. I tried to hardcode the MSPE and ended up with

```
MSEP <- function(df){
  df <- df[, -1] # Removing "name" column
  factor <- 1/nrow(df)
  summa <- 0
  for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    df_ny <- df[-i, ]
    fit <- lm(CO ~., data = df_ny)
    holder <- (df[i,]$CO - predict.lm(fit, df[i, ]))^2
    summa <- summa + holder
  }
  return(factor*summa)
}
```

Is this correct? Is there a built in function in R I can use to compare my result?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
in_sample <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100),
                        y = rnorm(100))
out_sample <- data.frame(y = rnorm(100),
                         x = rnorm(100))
mod <- lm(y ~ x, in_sample)

mspe <- function(model, dv, data) {
  yhat <- predict(model, newdata=data)
  y <- data[[dv]]
  mean((y - yhat)^2)
}

mspe(mod, "y", out_sample)
#> [1] 0.8247627
```